# Laravel - query builder - left join polymorphic relationship, distinct only

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, laravel-query-builder

So I'm using Vue 2.0 and Laravel 5.3 to create an application.

I've implemented my own sortable table with Vue, using the built-in pagination provided by Laravel.

Everything's working perfect - except, I'm trying to left join a "media" polymorphic table, so I can show an image in my table.

To enable sorting, I've had to use the query builder, as you can't sort on a relationship using Eloquent (AFAIK).

I define my relationships like:

```php
$inventories = $inventories->leftjoin('users as inventory_user', 'inventories.user_id', '=', 'inventory_user.id');
$inventories = $inventories->leftjoin('categories as category', 'inventories.category_id', '=', 'category.id');
$inventories = $inventories->leftjoin('inventories as parent', 'inventories.parent_id', '=', 'parent.id');
```

Which work great. However, how exactly do I left join a polymorphic relationship, without repeating (duplicating) any of the rows?

I've got this:

```
$inventories = $inventories->leftJoin('media', function($q) {
    $q->on('media.model_id', '=', 'inventories.id');
    $q->where('media.model_type', '=', 'App\Models\Inventory');
});
```

Which does show media (if it has a relation in the polymorphic table). However, if for instance I have 5 images (media) for 1 particular inventory item, my query repeats the inventory for however media there are, which in my case it's repeated 5 times.

This is my select query:

```
    $inventories = $inventories->select(DB::raw("
            inventories.id as inventory_id,
            inventories.name as inventory_name,
            inventories.order_column as inventory_order_column,
            category.id as category_id,
            category.name as category_name,
            parent.name as parent_name,
            parent.id as parent_id,
            inventories.updated_at as inventory_updated_at,
            media.name
    "));
```

I think I need to use a groupBy, but I'm not sure where I define it. If I do

```php
$inventories = $inventories->groupBy('inventories.id');
```

I get 
`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'test.inventories.name' isn't in GROUP BY...`

Has anyone been in a similar situation or know where to put my groupBy to show 1/distinct inventory items?

**EDIT:**

I was able to fix by using:

```
$inventories = $inventories->leftJoin('media', function($q) {
    $q->on('media.model_id', '=', 'inventories.id');
    $q->where('media.model_type', '=', 'App\Models\Inventory');
    $q->orderBy('media.order_column', 'asc');
    $q->groupBy('model.model_id');
});
```

and then setting `strict => false` in my `database.php`.

Comment: The issue is with the grouping. See the answer I added below

Comment: FWIW, I would not call it a fix, a workaround at best. Add the column name ('model.mode_id' from your example) you are grouping by to SELECT statement and the error will be gone and you can/should keep the strict setting on.

Comment: If I ever look at that codebase again, I'll have to check that out! I remember feeling queazy about disabling `strict` but workaround fixed it, so I forgot about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error states this issue occurs when `name` column not being in `GROUP BY` clause.

To solve this change

```
'strict' => true,
```

In `mysql` configuration under `connections` in your `config/database.php` file to

```
'strict' => false,
```

Additionally I would highly encourage to use [polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) over left join with eloquent.

Comment: Thanks, Gayan! I originally found that fix here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15232 but didn't want to disable strict mode, as I didn't know what the repercussions were. I have since disabled it and it's working.

I am indeed using polymorphic relations, which do work fine. However, I'm using the query builder, so I have to manually connect my tables via joins. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I meant this issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14997#issuecomment-242129087

Comment: Glad you found it helpfull. More on `mysql strict mode` could found here https://mattstauffer.co/blog/strict-mode-and-other-mysql-customizations-in-laravel-5-2

Comment: Ah, that explains so much! Thanks Gayan!

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll add it here:

```
$categories = $categories->select(DB::raw("
        inventories.id as inventory_id,
        inventories.name as inventory_name,
        inventories.order_column as inventory_order_column,
        category.id as category_id,
        category.name as category_name,
        parent.name as parent_name,
        parent.id as parent_id,
        inventories.updated_at as inventory_updated_at,
        media.name
"))->groupBy('inventories.id');
```